# how to get value of next column below previous column in DB2 Sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table as below, i want to get the OUT column value below the IN column and adding a new record.

```sql
    create table Temp (
    [name] varchar(10),
    [In] varchar(10),
    [Out] varchar(10),
    [HRs] varchar(10),
    ); 
    
    insert into Temp values('bob','login','logout','8');
    insert into Temp values('alice','login','logout','9');
    insert into Temp values('peter','login',null,'0');
```

Table output

| NAME | IN | OUT | HRs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | login | logout | 8 |
| alice | login | logout | 9 |
| peter | login | NULL | 0 |

Expected Output

| NAME | IN | HRs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | login | 8 |
| bob | logout | 8 |
| alice | login | 9 |
| alice | logout | 9 |
| peter | login | 0 |
| peter | NULL | 0 |

I need to achieve the above output on the Temp table combining the IN & OUT columns into IN column, how to achieve this in DB2 sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses union:

```sql
SELECT NAME, "IN", HRs
FROM
(
    SELECT NAME, "IN", HRs, 1 AS pos FROM Temp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NAME, "OUT", HRs, 2 FROM Temp
) t
ORDER BY NAME, pos;
```